# RegEx cannot extract param

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a URL in the following format: `http://website.com/item/1`

This is my rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)/ item.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

When I try to get the id with `$_GET['id']` and then echo it I get nothing.

What causes this?

Comment: Your URL is missing the trailing slash you have in the regex.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the trailing slash or make it optional.

```
RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+) item.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)/? item.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```